# Solve system of implicit ODE with Scilab

Tags: math, physics, modeling, ode, scilab

I'm modelling an overhead crane and obtained the following equations:
[image]

I'm noob when it comes to Scilab and so far I only simullated (using ODE) linear systems with no more than two degrees of freedom, which are simple systems that I can easily convert to am matrix and integrate it using ODE.

But this system in particular I have no clue how to simulate it, not because of the sin and cos functions, but because of the fact that I don't know how to put it in a state space matrix.

I've looked for a few tutorials (listed bellow) but I didn't understand any of those, can somebody tell me how I do it, or at least point where I could learn it?

http://www.openeering.com/sites/default/files/Nonlinear_Systems_Scilab.pdf
http://www.math.univ-metz.fr/~sallet/ODE_Scilab.pdf

Thank you, and sorry about my english

Answer (score 0):

The usual form means writing in terms of first order derivatives.  So you'll have relations where the 2nd derivative terms will be written as:

```
x'' = d(x')/fx
```

Substitute these into the equations you have.  You'll end up with eight simultaneous ODEs to solve instead of four, with appropriate initial conditions.

Comment: You probably mean `x'' = f(x, x')` becomes `x' = x1` and `x1' = f(x, x1)`. Otherwise `x'' = x'` means that the solution should be `x(t) = c1*exp(t) + c2`.

Comment: Poor job on my part. You're correct. All 2nd derivatives need to be expressed as 1st order ODEs.

Answer (score 0):

Although this ODE system is implicit, you can solve it with a classical (explicit) ODE solver by reformulating it this way: if you define `X=(x,L,theta,q)^T` then your system can be reformulated using matrix algebra as `A(X,X') * X" = B(X,X')`. Please note that the first order form of this system is

```
d/dt(X,X') = ( X', A(X,X')^(-1)*B(X,X') )
```

Suppose now that you have defined two Scilab functions `A` and `B` which actually compute their values w.r.t. to the values of `X`and `X'`

```
function out = A(X,Xprime)
    x=X(1)
    L=X(2)
    theta=X(3)
    qa=X(4)
    xd=XPrime(1)
    Ld=XPrime(2)
    thetad=XPrime(3)
    qa=XPrime(4);
    ...
end
function out = B(X,Xprime)
    ...
end
```

then the right hand side of the system of 8 ODEs, as it can be given to the `ode` function of Scilab can be coded as follows

```
function dstate_dt = rhs(t,state)
    X      = state(1:4);
    Xprime = state(5:8);
    out    = [ Xprime
               A(X,Xprime) \ B(X,Xprime)]
end
```

Writing the code of `A()` and `B()` according to the given equations is the only remaining (but quite easy) task.